# Advantages/disadvantages of a ring or stair design for long page websites

Tags: website-design, design-patterns

I'm currently planning for my personal website, which I plan to make as a long page website. (See [this](http://fuelyourfuture.com.au/) for an example of a long page website)

As how I imagine my **Experience** section, it will continually grow (obviously), therefore, I have thought of a possible design to be able to show all my work experience, and at the same time, avoiding tedious scrolling when someone doesn't really want to read all of the entries.

As for all long page website designs, the "order" of information will be vertical (top to bottom).

In the case of my figure below, the user would be able to traverse it from About Me -> Experience (and skip the jobs) -> All other sections -> End.

## Ring Design

[image: Ring Design]

After reading through all the jobs, you would return to the **Experience section**.

## Stair Design

[image: Stair Design]

After reading through all the jobs, you would move on to the **Next section**, whatever that may be.

**What would you advise for my situation? What are the advantages and disadvantages of both?**

---

Note : Please pardon the unattractive images.

Note 2 : I don't know if these types of design patterns have a name, and I just made up the design names **Ring** and **Stair**.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really offer any expertise, per-se, but I can tell you that my brain immediately wrapped around your Ring design while the Stair design took a bit of analysis.  You don't always wanna play to the simpletons, but the simplicity of the Ring design makes it the superior choice in my mind.

EDIT :: Also, the Ring design lends itself more readily to users cycling through the content, as opposed to navigating to things in different directions (? - for lack of a better term).  Users being able to cycle through information is often a valuable thing for both users and creators.